# Does iOS9 support Web Notifications?

Tags: html, safari, ios9, web-notifications

Does iOS 9 mobile Safari support the [Web Notifications API](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/)?

I can't find any sources pointing at new HTML5 features except for this [one](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH9-SW5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications) and [HTML5test](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ios-9.0.html) they don't support it.

To be honest, it isn't likely from Apples point-of-view to allow it, since it moves away from their own platform and it will have a negative impact on the battery since it has to keep the browser and its network connections alive.

Comment: Why does it move away from their platform? And what would be the reason to support it on OSX then?

Comment: It makes it easier to make sites work on non-iOS devices. This is surely not something Apple would want to support. It will also drain the battery since it can't fully suspend the browser and its network connections.

Comment: The first point isn't a reason for me. This would put it into question why Apple supports W3C standards at all. And is it really that harmful to battery lifetime if the browser needs to run in a background thread? Isn't that how native apps behave in general?

Comment: Do they support OGG? The `color` input type? No. They don't support all available parts of any standard, including HTML5. And they aren't required. They can do as they wish.

Comment: You're completely right but I still think that they will support it one day or at least an alternative implementation. Anyway thanks for your response! I'll going to accept it.

Comment: Apple prefers people to use native apps on web apps, they have more control of native apps which they only allow to be installed through the iTunes app store. That way they also get 30% of all app purchase/in app purchase - so they make intentionally a few measures to cripple the open web apps and keep make native apps preferable. One of these steps is not support web app notifications - or delay support as much as possible.